# GCC and Clang perform extremely slow on mod of power of 2 operation

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, clang, modulo

Consider following code:

```
int foo(int x) {
  if ((x) % 256 == 0)
    if ((x) % 16 == 0)
      return 0;
  return 1;
}

int bar(int x) {
  if ((x) & 255 == 0)
    if ((x) & 15 == 0)
      return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

I think those two function's assembly code are equivalent since modern compiler such as GCC and Clang will do the `% X` optimization that change this operation to `& (X-1)` which X is a *constant power of two*. But unfortunately, Clang seems [**not**](https://quick-bench.com/q/zpRtOG4nDGOVZXR2ImV9UzzwCdQ) do this optimization, should this be a performance issue bug for Clang?

Then I change the code to:

```
int foo(int x) {
  if ((x + 1) % 256 == 0)
    if ((x + 1) % 16 == 0)
      return 0;
  return 1;
}

int bar(int x) {
  if ((x + 1) & 255 == 0)
    if ((x + 1) & 15 == 0)
      return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

There occurs a huge performance gap in both GCC and Clang, they perform extremely slow on function `foo` even I turn on `O3`. GCC perform on `foo` is [**7.5 times slower than**](https://quick-bench.com/q/U-af5apgZz9A4fmhJHHlfcCycrs) perform on `bar` with 100000 iterations, and Clang perform on `foo` is [**still ~30000 times slower than**](https://quick-bench.com/q/zpRtOG4nDGOVZXR2ImV9UzzwCdQ) `bar`.

Is there some issue that both Compiler can't do the `% X` optimization in such case?

Comment: Are the parentheses correct? `==` has higher operator precedence than bitwise `&`. Maybe the problem is that `bar` is computing `if (x & (255 == 0))` instead of `if((x & 255) == 0)`?

Comment: Yeah, Nathan Pierson's right, it looks like you're comparing different things https://quick-bench.com/q/K9FBYunBf6r6tHbYJt5aGir2i-s

Comment: @cigien wow, that is a big mistake. thanks!

Comment: No worries, happens to everyone :)

Comment: I was wondering about the strange optimization until I became aware of the precedence issue. (With correct parentheses, both functions result in precise same code as expected.) [**Demo on Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/vs799v) ;-)

Comment: Okay, yeah, because as written `bar` can just get optimized entirely to `return 1`, which is clearly gonna be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that the optimization you propose is wrong when the input value of `x` is negative.  If you change the type of `x` to be `unsigned` rather than `int`, then you'll see that both compilers do this optimization.

Comment: No, this just a operator precedence issue. `(x + 1) & 255 == 0` will perform `255 == 0`  first since  `== ` has higher operator precedence than bitwise  `& `.